# Use @unittest.skipIf skip test at runtime depends on variable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I want to skip specific test depends on variable in Class like below code.

But it will get "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable".

The **name** has been set in other place. (TestClassA.name = 'xxx')

Perhaps it's not a good method but I have no idea how to modify.

Please give me some suggestion, thanks.

```
class TestClassA(unittest.TestCase):
    name = None

    def test_a(self):
        //do something

    @unittest.skipIf('xxx' in name, "reason")
    def test_b(self):
        //do something
```

Answer (score 4):

well, you could work around this particular issue by having

```
class TestClassA:
    name = ''
```

but it most likely will not address the underlying problem -> the collection of the tests happens before they are executed, so setting the class variable after the tests are collected won't cause the test to be skipped...

maybe you could import `name` in the module's scope from some configuration file instead of setting it on the class?

e.g.

```
from someconfig.module import NAME

class TestClassA:

    def test_a(self):
        //do something

    @unittest.skipIf('xxx' in NAME, "reason")
    def test_b(self):
        //do something
```